# How to remove extremely annoying PowerBI Pop-up?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Since the Juni update, I regularly get a really anoying popup in the DAX editor in powerBI whenever I press ctrl-enter. Does anyone know how to turn this 'feature' off?

This is the popup:

[image: "Tips for using Power BI with a screen reader. / Skip to main content. / Also you can press "?" to show keyboard shortcuts."]

It is particularly annoying considering it can't be closed or ignored with escape as it loses focus as soon as it appears. Pressing ESC will result in your measure rolling back to the last evaluated state...

Alt-enter doesn't do it for me, it doesn't move along with the indentation and it produces a windows warning sound as well (less annoying that the pop-up though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior in the July EN-US version as well. If I want the pop-up to close while not losing the measure formula, I am able to hit enter Enter twice. I'll get the usual DAX error in my formula bar if my measure is incomplete, but it saves my work and allows me to select the formula bar and continue working.

If you are trying to get a new line in your DAX formula, try using Shift+Enter instead. I just tried it, and it seems to respect the indentation from the previous row.

Comment: I logged a bug for this with the Power BI team. Hopefully it will be fixed in a future release.